# Crystal Reports 2013: Conditional rendering based on export format

Tags: crystal-reports

I am developing a report in Crystal Reports 2013 to publish to a Business Objects server.  The user wants it to be able to run to HTML, PDF, Excel, or CSV.  If I make it compatible with CSV (a raw data dump with one row per record -- for use downstream by a machine) it will be too wide to fit on one page for the PDF output.  We have no direct control of the Business Objects server.  This is all done through the cloud application.

...and I'm new to Crystal Reports...

Is there a way to create two sections in the report -- one for CSV and one for PDF -- and have one render (or hide) when the report is run to Excel or CSV and the other render (or hide) when the report is run to HTML or PDF?  How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can create a parameter that prompts the user for desired layout ("For PDF", "For CSV") and use that parameter in the dynamic expression for section suppress attribute.

Comment: I tested this and it works.  But my report is running through an application that is using a Business Objects BI server.  The user is already asked to choose the output format, so I don't want to ask them again.  The application knows what format was requested, so it should just pass the information along to the report -- but it doesn't.  Now we'll see if the application vendor will implement technology to allow me to wire up this feature to the application features.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they don't, you can always go to plan B and simply create 2 different reports.